# How to search array with LIKE function?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table with an array column like:

```
1   {orange_123,apple,grape}
2   {guava,apple_123,durian}
3   {strawberry_123,lime_123,leomon_123}
4   {mango_123,mangosteen,plum}
5   {plum,guava,peach}
```

I search for rows where all array elements have '_123' as a suffix.
Should return only this row:

```
3   {strawberry_123,lime_123,leomon_123}
```

But it doesn't work.

```
with basket_tbl as (
select 1 as id, array['orange_123', 'apple', 'grape'] as item union
select 2 as id, array['guava', 'apple_123', 'durian'] as item union
select 3 as id, array['strawberry_123', 'lime_123', 'leomon_123'] as item union
select 4 as id, array['mango_123', 'mangosteen', 'plum'] as item union
select 5 as id, array['plum', 'guava', 'peach'] as item
)
SELECT * 
FROM basket_tbl bt
WHERE '%_123' LIKE ANY(bt.item)
```

Any good idea?

Comment: Terrible data model, one of your next questions will be how to improve the performance… This is slow by design. Create a basic model based on 3NF and you will be fine

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is; you simply use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause with `NOT EXISTS` to filter out records that have at least one element without the `_123` suffix. I also have used ***[`unnest()`](https://www.sqliz.com/postgresql-ref/unnest/)*** function to expand the array into set of rows for computation. A sample query would look something like:

```sql
WITH basket_tbl AS (
  -- basket table entries
)
SELECT id, item
FROM basket_tbl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM unnest(item) AS element
  WHERE element NOT LIKE '%_123'
);
-- Outputs:
-- id   items
-- 3    ["strawberry_123","lime_123","leomon_123"]
```

*[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xewgaBQW9eqqizeYvx7yQw/0)*

Comment: @augustus666: Note that this includes rows with `null` or empty array. You did not specify, but you may want to exclude those.